# ReactJS - Form Validation Error for gmail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

I have a login page, and I need to validate the input for a gmail ie. the name should be of the gmail format. I am quite sure that the logic of the function works properly, but there is some issue in the part where the function is declared and called. This is my code:

```
const Login = () => {
    // const [name,setName] = useState('Shakthi Saravanan');
    // const {data:blogs, isPending, error} = useFetch('http://localhost:8000/blogs');

    function handleChange(field, e) {
        let fields = this.state.fields;
        fields[field] = e.target.value;
        this.setState({ fields });
      }

    function handleValidation() {
        let fields = this.state.fields;
        let errors = {};
        let formIsValid = true;

        //Name
        if (!fields["name"]) {
        formIsValid = false;
        errors["name"] = "Cannot be empty";
        }

        if (typeof fields["name"] !== "undefined") {
        if (!fields["name"].match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {
            formIsValid = false;
            errors["name"] = "Only letters";
        }
        }

        //Email
        if (!fields["email"]) {
        formIsValid = false;
        errors["email"] = "Cannot be empty";
        }

        if (typeof fields["email"] !== "undefined") {
        let lastAtPos = fields["email"].lastIndexOf("@");
        let lastDotPos = fields["email"].lastIndexOf(".");

        if (
            !(
            lastAtPos < lastDotPos &&
            lastAtPos > 0 &&
            fields["email"].indexOf("@@") == -1 &&
            lastDotPos > 2 &&
            fields["email"].length - lastDotPos > 2
            )
        ) {
            formIsValid = false;
            errors["email"] = "Email is not valid";
        }
        }

        this.setState({ errors: errors });
        return formIsValid;
    }
    
    return ( 
        <div className="login-cot bg-danger" id="layoutAuthentication">
                    
            <div id="layoutAuthentication_content">
                <main>
                    <div className="container ">
                        
                        <div className="row justify-content-center ">
                            
                            <div className="col-lg-5 ">
                               
                                <div className="card shadow-lg border-0 rounded-lg mt-5 bg-secondary">
                                    <center><h1 className="bg-warning" style={{padding:"10px",}}><b><BsBugFill /><BsTools /> <BsColumns />  BFP</b></h1></center>
                                    <div className="card-header"><h3 className="text-center my-1"><b>Login</b></h3></div>
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <form>
                                            <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                                                <input className="form-control" id="inputEmail" type="email"
                                                 onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, "name")} placeholder="name@example.com"
                                                 value={this.state.fields["name"]} />
                                                <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                                                <input className="form-control" id="inputPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                                                <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                                            </div>
                                           
                                            <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mt-4 mb-0">
                                                <Link className="small text-light" to="/forgotPassword">Forgot Password?</Link>
                                                <Link className="btn btn-success" to="/home">Login</Link>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
     );
}
```

But I am running into an error :

[image: Error]
Although I am sure the variable is declared correctly.
Is it necessary that I have to render it into a class?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: this style of code needs class Login extends Component.

What "this" really means in Javascript is really unintuitive and has to do from with the context where the function is called if I remember correctly.

By creating a class in React you get something similar to what you would expect in more standard object oriented languages. Also this.state etc. is functionalitity of a Component so without extending this wont work, make sure you initialize state. If you want to work functionally you can use effects & hooks.